# Como mostrar datos obtenidos a traves de un Fetch en ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, api

No estoy pudiendo "mapear" los datos obtenidos en un `json` con un `Fetch` en React.

Eh intentado guardar los datos una Lista, con `componentDidMount()`, mapearlos directamente, pero sin éxito alguno.

Me fije si los datos llegaban desde la API a React con un console.log() al json y si, están llegando correctamente. Los quiero mostrar en forma de tabla, pero como digo, no logro hacerlo..

Asi lo estoy recibiendo:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      cliente:[],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://localhost:7079/cliente/listarClientes")  
     .then(response =>response.json())
     .then( json => console.log(json))
  }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y los trato de mostrar en la tabla:

```
 render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Clientes</h2>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Nombre</th>
              <th>Correo</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.state.cliente.map((cli) => (
              <tr key={cli.ID}>
                <td>{cli.ID}</td>
                <td>{cli.Nombre}</td>
                <td>{cli.Correo}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Probé cambiando el `componentDidMount()` por éste:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://localhost:7079/cliente/listarClientes")  
     .then(response =>response.json())
     .then(result => {
      this.setState({cliente:result});
     })
  }
```

Tambien utilicé Hooks para poder resolverlo y nada..

```
  const [repos, setRepos] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get(`https://localhost:7079/cliente/listarClientes`);
        setRepos(response.data);
    }

    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Pero me tira una seguidillas de errores...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien probé con un `useEffect()` y `useState()`

```
function Activity() {
  function LoadActivity() {
    fetch("https://localhost:7079/cliente/listarClientes")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => console.log(data));
  }

  const [activity, setActivity] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    LoadActivity();
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{activity}</h1>
      <button>Cargar Más</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Activity;
```

Y con `console.log(data)` se muestran los datos correctamente, pero despues si hago `setActivity(data)`, me tira los mismos errores...

No entiendo qué podré estar haciendo mal...

Comment: en tu primera implementación usando clases tu problema es que en el componentDidMount al llamar el setState estás asignando directamente result y no result.data

Answer (score 0):

El problema es sencillo no estás guardando correctamente el resultado en el estado de la aplicación, cuando haces el

```
function Activity() {
  function LoadActivity() {
    fetch("https://localhost:7079/cliente/listarClientes")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => console.log(data));
  }

  const [activity, setActivity] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    LoadActivity();
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{activity}</h1>
      <button>Cargar Más</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Activity;
```

En esta línea `.then((data) => console.log(data));` no estás guardando el resultado lo estás mostrando, por lo que tienes que crear una variable de estado y hacer

```
.then((result) => setData(result.data));
```

Recordándote que tú respuesta es un objeto con tres claves `message`, `status` y `data` por eso el `result.data`.

De esta manera podrás hacer un map así:

```
{data.map((cli) => (
  <tr key={cli.id}>
    <td>{cli.id}</td>
    <td>{cli.nombre}</td>
    <td>{cli.correo}</td>
  </tr>
))}
```

Resaltó que este ejemplo es válido para los componentes de función, pero aplicable a los componentes de clase.